# how to train a prompt for voice input of slider value

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

How do I provide training for handsfree entry of a slider value?

[image]

[image]

```
render {
    form {
      elements {
        slider {
          id (howmuchinfouserprefers)
          min-value (1)
          max-value (5)
          min-label (1 - Minimal)
          max-label (5 - Everything)
          step (1)
          type (HowMuchInfoUserPrefers)
          value ("#{raw(howmuchinfouserprefers)}")

        }
      }
      on-submit {
        goal: HowMuchInfoUserPrefers
        value: viv.core.FormElement(howmuchinfouserprefers)
      }
    }
```

When I say "three" here with handsfree on, it does not proceed forward, just stays stuck on the slider request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing the correct training. Regardless the input form element type, the training for voice input is the same prompt training.

Here is a working example, as the number 3 is input from the left panel instead of slider bar. You can [download can try](https://github.com/MinChengVivLabs/example.inputWithName). Utterance "list all names" --> click "John" --> click "enter age" --> type 45 in form and click "go" --> in the view with slider bar use left panel **type 3 and press enter**

[image]

Here is the planner from debugger
[image]